# Don't know why I'm getting the error masses invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c

I need help. I'm learning c programming. I understand the error message, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried to make "TEMPS" a float or a string. It doesn't work either.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEMPS 12

int main()
{
    int temperature[TEMPS];
    int counter;
    
    temperature[0] = 70;
    temperature[1] = 60;
    temperature[2] = 20;
    temperature[3] = 80;
    temperature[4] = 90;
    temperature[5] = 72;
    temperature[6] = 89;
    temperature[7] = 40;
    temperature[8] = 88;
    temperature[9] = 72;
    temperature[10] = 78;
    temperature[11] = 91;
    
    for (counter=0; counter<TEMPS; counter++) {
        printf("Daily the average temperature in month %d and press ENTER %d\n",
               TEMPS[counter],
               temperature[counter]);
    }
    
    printf("The temperatures over the past 12 months are\n");
    
    for (counter=0; counter<12; counter++) {
        printf(" %d ", temperature[counter]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `TEMPS[counter]` ?? i.e. `12[counter]`. Looks like a typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TEMPS[counter]
```

TEMPS is not an array but an integer

```
printf("Daily the average temperature in month %d and press ENTER %d \n", counter, temperature[counter]);
```

I haven't looked in detail in what you are trying to achieve  but the line above looks better to me.